# Using Scala's Macros to enforce type equality

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10, scala-macros

I've been experimenting with MacroParadise ([here](http://scalamacros.org/news/2012/12/18/macro-paradise.html) and [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html)), as well a few other newer features. Today while using TypeTags, I came to the realization that I can now do something like this to enforce type equality.

```
def typeEq[A: TypeTag, B: TypeTag]: Boolean = {
    implicitly[TypeTag[A]].tpe =:= implicitly[TypeTag[B]].tpe
}
```

I then remembered that `TypeTag` implicits are compiler generated, and I had the idea that I may be able write a macro enabling more concise TypeTag usage like this:

```
def foo[A](xs: List[A]): String = xs match {
  case y :: ys if typeEq[A, String] => y
  case y :: ys if typeEq[A, Int]    => y.toString 
}
```

I've only written a handful of macros in Lisp, and am stumbling around attempting to use the macro library. This lead me to several attempts, but they all end up expanding to something like `Int =:= Int` which doesn't work, or something like `typeA =:= typeB` where both are free(which also doesn't work).

This lead me to two questions:
 1) Is this possible to do without the Context Bounds on `foo`(like written above)?
 2) How do I correctly splice the `Type`s obtained by the implicits into the result expression?

It seems to me that macros and implicits should allow me to fetch the `WeakTypeTag` implicit and use its `tpe` member for splicing, since they both occur at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

You can already enforce type equality by using the type `=:=[From,To]`:

```
def bar[A,B](a:A,b:B)(implicit ev: A =:= B)= (a,b)

bar(1,1)
res0: (Int, Int) = (1,2)

bar(1,"3")

error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: =:=[Int,java.lang.String]
       bar(1,"3")
          ^
```

**edit**:

Sorry, got your question a little wrong, I guess. Your example almost works, but the compiler can't know, what `A` is, so it can't find an evidence of `TypeTag[A]`. If you add the context bound to the method definition it will work:

```
def foo[A : TypeTag](xs: List[A]) = xs match {
  case _ if typeEq[A, String] => "yay"
  case _ => "noes"
}

scala> foo(List(2))
res0: String = noes

scala> foo(List(""))
res1: String = yay
```

**edit2**:

For your example you actually don't need `TypeTag`s at all, you can just use pattern matching, as you only use the first element:

```
def foo[A](xs: List[A]): String = xs match {
  case (y: String) :: _ => y
  case y :: _ => y.toString
}

scala> foo(List(1,2,3))
res6: String = 1

scala> foo(List("foo"))
res7: String = foo
```

But be aware, thath the pattern mathcing is non-exhaustive, because it does not handle `Nil`.

Comment: This is fine for asserting equality on just two types, but the =:= type witness is not usable in the body due to erasure. A call foo[Int] and foo[String] are identical at runtime, you need a mechanism for recovering the erased information (i.e. TypeTags). I'm interested in having a concise way of stating type equality between the two types, regardless of erasure. If you replace `typeEq[ty1, ty2]` with `ty1 =:= ty2` the above example will not compile. It is also worth noting that =:= is actually a method on `scala.runtime.reflect.Type` not the class =:=, that is used for an implicit witness.

Comment: Thanks, that does solve my example (albeit a contrived one). I'm more interested in the macro writing part. I'm was still having trouble splicing the types correctly. This is more important for a case where the `A` may not be the same as the type of `xs.head` or with other structures.

Comment: Can you please give such an example?